# Show Plugin menu to multiple wordpress user roles

Tags: wordpress

I want to show a plugin menu to administrators(`manage_options`) and Shop Managers(`shop_manager`). Right now its only showing menu to `shop_manager`.

```
function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_options_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'Avg Order Completion Time', 'shop_manager', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing the capability to **manage_woocommerce**

replace

`add_options_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'Avg Order Completion Time', 'shop_manager', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );`

to

```
 add_options_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'Avg Order Completion Time', 'manage_woocommerce', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution but this is what I did. I created multiple actions to call the same function both time with one of the .

```
function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_options_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'Avg Order Completion Time', 'shop_manager', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
}
function my_plugin_menu2() {
    add_options_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'Avg Order Completion Time', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
}
```